# What is the difference between route and path in EmberJs

Tags: ember.js

What is the difference between route and path in EmberJs

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('about');
  this.route('contact', { path: '/getting-in-touch' });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first argument to `route` is the name of the route. It's used to find the right files to load `app/routes/about.js` and to provide links `<LinkTo @route="about">About</LinkTo>`. If you provide a `path` option it is used to create the URL you see in the location bar for the browser.

From the [ember guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_basic-routes)

> You can leave off the path if it is the same as the route name.

For your case the following are equivalent:

```js
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('about', { path: '/about' });
  this.route('contact', { path: '/getting-in-touch' });
});
```

```js
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('about');
  this.route('contact', { path: '/getting-in-touch' });
});
```

Will results in Ember knowing how to load URLs for `https://yoursite.com/about` and `https://yoursite.com/getting-in-touch`

And for `<LinkTo @route="contact">Contact Us</LinkTo>` to create a link with HTML like `<a href="https://yoursite.com/getting-in-touch">Contact Us</a>`